# Formatear Documentos en Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, vscode

Estaba buscando información de como configurar el formateo de documentos en *visual studio code* para C, y esta el atajo `control+shift+i` pero me deja los corchetes por debajo de la función buscando mas información entro a las configuraciones
[image: Imagen 1]

Y me abre un monton de configuraciones:
Archivo: .editorconfig

```
[*]
cpp_indent_braces=false
cpp_indent_multi_line_relative_to=innermost_parenthesis
cpp_indent_within_parentheses=indent
cpp_indent_preserve_within_parentheses=false
cpp_indent_case_labels=false
cpp_indent_case_contents=true
cpp_indent_case_contents_when_block=false
cpp_indent_lambda_braces_when_parameter=true
cpp_indent_goto_labels=one_left
cpp_indent_preprocessor=leftmost_column
cpp_indent_access_specifiers=false
cpp_indent_namespace_contents=true
cpp_indent_preserve_comments=false
cpp_new_line_before_open_brace_namespace=ignore
cpp_new_line_before_open_brace_type=ignore
cpp_new_line_before_open_brace_function=ignore
cpp_new_line_before_open_brace_block=ignore
cpp_new_line_before_open_brace_lambda=ignore
cpp_new_line_scope_braces_on_separate_lines=false
cpp_new_line_close_brace_same_line_empty_type=false
cpp_new_line_close_brace_same_line_empty_function=false
cpp_new_line_before_catch=true
cpp_new_line_before_else=true
cpp_new_line_before_while_in_do_while=false
cpp_space_before_function_open_parenthesis=remove
cpp_space_within_parameter_list_parentheses=false
cpp_space_between_empty_parameter_list_parentheses=false
cpp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements=true
cpp_space_within_control_flow_statement_parentheses=false
cpp_space_before_lambda_open_parenthesis=false
cpp_space_within_cast_parentheses=false
cpp_space_after_cast_close_parenthesis=false
cpp_space_within_expression_parentheses=false
cpp_space_before_block_open_brace=true
cpp_space_between_empty_braces=false
cpp_space_before_initializer_list_open_brace=false
cpp_space_within_initializer_list_braces=true
cpp_space_preserve_in_initializer_list=true
cpp_space_before_open_square_bracket=false
cpp_space_within_square_brackets=false
cpp_space_before_empty_square_brackets=false
cpp_space_between_empty_square_brackets=false
cpp_space_group_square_brackets=true
cpp_space_within_lambda_brackets=false
cpp_space_between_empty_lambda_brackets=false
cpp_space_before_comma=false
cpp_space_after_comma=true
cpp_space_remove_around_member_operators=true
cpp_space_before_inheritance_colon=true
cpp_space_before_constructor_colon=true
cpp_space_remove_before_semicolon=true
cpp_space_after_semicolon=false
cpp_space_remove_around_unary_operator=true
cpp_space_around_binary_operator=insert
cpp_space_around_assignment_operator=insert
cpp_space_pointer_reference_alignment=left
cpp_space_around_ternary_operator=insert
cpp_wrap_preserve_blocks=one_liners
```

estuve probando configuraciones y me molestaba que siguiera todo igual independiente de los cambios que hiciera ejempló si quiero cambiar el orden de las coma con la instrucción `cpp_space_after_comma=true` la cambio por `false` le doy a guardar y seguido apretó `control+shift+i`, el cambio que hice no se aplica sigue exactamente igual, el caso es que me gustaría poner los corchetes al lado de la función y no por debajo pero aun así no se me aplica los cambios y no encuentro la instrucción para hacer el cambio de corchetes, ¿alguna solución para que los cambios se apliquen al formateo?¿Cual es la instrucción que me deja cambiar los corchetes?

la informacion la saque de aqui:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/cpp-editorconfig-properties?view=vs-2019

Lo que quiero

```
void funcion(){
    codigo....
}
```

lo que tengo

```
void funcion()
{
    codigo....
}
```

Archivo : c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/mpich",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich" //libreria con la cual trabajo
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Como se puede ver en el Archivo.c se tiene un código dentando con los paréntesis al lado de la función
Archivo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define TAG1 1
#define TAG2 2
#define MASTER 0
#define X1 1
#define X2 2

int whoami, hm_are_we;
MPI_Status status;

/*
 *
 * Shows the usage of the program
 *
 */
void Usage(char *message){

    printf("\nUsage : mpirun -np 3 %s a b c\n", message);
    fflush(stdout);
}

/*
 *
 */
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME]; //T0
    int me;                                      //T1
    float coef[3];                               //T2
    float delta;                                 //T3
    float x;                                     //T4
    float x1;                                    //T5
    float x2;                                    //T6
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                      //T7
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &hm_are_we);   //T8

    if (hm_are_we == 3){                                                  // T9
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &whoami);                           //T11
        MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &me);                      //T12
        printf("\n\nProcess [%d] Alive on %s\n", whoami, processor_name); //T13
        fflush(stdout);                                                   //14
        if (whoami == MASTER)                                             //T15
            if (argc == 4){                                               //T17
                coef[0] = atof(argv[1]);                                  //T19
                coef[1] = atof(argv[2]);                                  //T20
                coef[2] = atof(argv[3]);                                  //T21
                MPI_Send(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, X1, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //T22
                MPI_Send(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, X2, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //T23
                MPI_Recv(&x1, 1, MPI_FLOAT, X1, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);      //T24
                MPI_Recv(&x2, 1, MPI_FLOAT, X2, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);      //T25
                printf("\n\nReal Solutions of %fx^2 + %fx + %f = 0 are x1 = %f x2 = %f\n\n", coef[0], coef[1], coef[2], x1, x2); //T26
                fflush(stdout);                                                                                                  //T27
            }
            else                //T18
                Usage(argv[0]); //T28
        else{                                                                     //T16
            MPI_Recv(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //T29
            delta = sqrt(coef[1] * coef[1] - 4.0 * coef[0] * coef[2]);            //T30
            if (whoami == X1)                                                     //T31
                x = (-coef[1] + delta) / (2.0 * coef[0]);                         //T33
            else                                                                  //T32
                x = (-coef[1] - delta) / (2.0 * coef[0]);                         //T34
            MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);             //T35
        }
    }               // T10
    MPI_Finalize(); //T36
}
```

si aplico el formato `control+shift+i` queda de la siguiente forma:

Archivo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define TAG1 1
#define TAG2 2
#define MASTER 0
#define X1 1
#define X2 2

int whoami, hm_are_we;
MPI_Status status;

/*
 *
 * Shows the usage of the program
 *
 */
void Usage(char *message)
{

    printf("\nUsage : mpirun -np 3 %s a b c\n", message);
    fflush(stdout);
}

/*
 *
 */
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME]; //T0
    int me;                                      //T1
    float coef[3];                               //T2
    float delta;                                 //T3
    float x;                                     //T4
    float x1;                                    //T5
    float x2;                                    //T6
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                      //T7
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &hm_are_we);   //T8

    if (hm_are_we == 3)
    {                                                                     // T9
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &whoami);                           //T11
        MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &me);                      //T12
        printf("\n\nProcess [%d] Alive on %s\n", whoami, processor_name); //T13
        fflush(stdout);                                                   //14
        if (whoami == MASTER)                                             //T15
            if (argc == 4)
            {                                                                                                                    //T17
                coef[0] = atof(argv[1]);                                                                                         //T19
                coef[1] = atof(argv[2]);                                                                                         //T20
                coef[2] = atof(argv[3]);                                                                                         //T21
                MPI_Send(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, X1, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                                                         //T22
                MPI_Send(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, X2, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                                                         //T23
                MPI_Recv(&x1, 1, MPI_FLOAT, X1, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);                                                  //T24
                MPI_Recv(&x2, 1, MPI_FLOAT, X2, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);                                                  //T25
                printf("\n\nReal Solutions of %fx^2 + %fx + %f = 0 are x1 = %f x2 = %f\n\n", coef[0], coef[1], coef[2], x1, x2); //T26
                fflush(stdout);                                                                                                  //T27
            }
            else                //T18
                Usage(argv[0]); //T28
        else
        {                                                                         //T16
            MPI_Recv(&coef, 3, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, TAG1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //T29
            delta = sqrt(coef[1] * coef[1] - 4.0 * coef[0] * coef[2]);            //T30
            if (whoami == X1)                                                     //T31
                x = (-coef[1] + delta) / (2.0 * coef[0]);                         //T33
            else                                                                  //T32
                x = (-coef[1] - delta) / (2.0 * coef[0]);                         //T34
            MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MASTER, TAG2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);             //T35
        }
    }               // T10
    MPI_Finalize(); //T36
}
```

Comment: en donde exactamente estas guardando la configuracion personalizada? cuales son todos los archivos en tu directorio? y que contenido tienen..

Comment: Las configuraciones las estoy guardando acutalmente en la carpeta que se esta trabajando, los archivos que tengo son 2, un `.c` y `.exe` el contenido del .c es realmente necesario?

Comment: lo digo porque cuando haces esa clase de modificaciones, vscode crea unos archivos `.json` que tienen montones de parametros en una carpeta oculta

Comment: me ha creado un archivo `.json` que me incluye un path de una libreria que no tenia y el compilador

Comment: Por favor publica el contenido de los archivos de tu directorio. Es nesesario tener la informacion especifica. Publicas un error que no es facil reproducir por falta de informacion

Comment: ahí están los directorios que tengo, espero que pueda ayudarte a entender, lamento la falta de información

Comment: Hola, gracias por la informacion, ahora que puedo ayudarte quiero entender como estas escribiendo para que te salgan los corchetes asi, tengo la solucion pero nesesito entender como estas usando el programa. Entiendo que escribes `main` + Tab o escribes de corriente todo con espacios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy sencillo a mi también me pasaba y que horror para encontrar una solución.
Lo primero es acceder a las opciones de Visual Studio con `Ctrl+,` Una vez ahí solo tienes que escribir `format` en la barra de búsqueda, te vas a la sección de C++ y buscan las opción de `C_Cpp: Formatting` y la pones a `vcFormat`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar la extensión Clang-Format. Después de instalar la extensión, debe reiniciar VSCode.

Una vez instalado, Para formatear el código, puede llamar a Command Palette nuevamente con

> Ctrl + Shift + P

, y luego ingresar “format”.

El atajo

> Ctrl + Shift + i

es para Linux . Si desea utilizarlo en de Windows , es necesario utilizar

> Alt + Shift + F

.

**Nota:** *Si no tiene Clang-Format instalado en su sistema, verá el mensaje:*

> The 'clang-format' command is not available. Please check your
> clang.formatTool user setting and ensure it is installed.

Éxitos!

Comment: esta bien la extensión, pero de igual manera me deja los corchetes por debajo, esta aplicando el mismo formateo que anteriormente, ¿sabe como cambiar el formato con `clang-format` ?